# Good Approach to modeling a Game Match in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I'm trying to have a model for a type of match in Rails. the match needs to keep track of the following:

- The two players
- The winner

no scores or anything like that. I could see doing this as 3 separate `has_one` relations to the player, but that seems hacky to me. Is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about just two fields:

```
class GameMatch < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :winner, :class_name => 'Player'
  belongs_to :loser, :class_name => 'Player'

end
```

If you need to enter the GameMatch into the system before the game is completed, you'll have to have three fields, but you could alternatively detail it like this:

```
class GameMatch < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :home_player, :class_name => 'Player'
  belongs_to :away_player, :class_name => 'Player'

  def winner
    self[:home_won] ? home_player : away_player
  end      

  def winner=(player)
    self[:home_won] = player == home_player
  end

end
```

Granted, you'll have to have some handling in there to make sure the winner played the game and wasn't an onlooker that decided to claim the victory.

Comment: very nicely described. I would like to add that if you ever need storing series of values, like round outcomes, hits and stuff, you can use serializable to store hashes in your model.

Comment: good call, and to optimize the table you could convert `:winner` to a boolean. heck, might as well alter the answer for that.