# How to run a scheduled job (match) in a football game with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cron

I am trying to build a football game using rails but have difficulty in building the match scheduling/result. While searching I have seen other people developing their team and match models by Club/Team has_many matches and Match belongs_to home_team and away_team like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310909/multiple-has-many-relationships-to-the-same-class),[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493508/rails-match-model) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517389/good-approach-to-modeling-a-game-match-in-rails).

What I cannot figure out is, say a user has scheduled a match with another user, supposedly 50 hours later. How should I schedule the match controller to run the function 50 hours later? By dynamically creating a cron job with the time and other_team parameters or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all relative to the complexity of the rules you want to implement. More or less, that is a [workflow](http://www.workflowpatterns.com/patterns/).

The simple and less worrisome path is to implement a state-based workflow maybe by using [stonepath](https://github.com/bokmann/stonepath) and implement cron job that polls the storage from time to time,  runs events, and pushes the state forward.

A more professional solution is to use a full blown workflow engine like [ruote](http://ruote.rubyforge.org/), that would work beautifully, but that would mean a separate daemon to keep running, failure handling routines for such a critical system, etc.

Comment: Probably because I have no programming background, I couldn't think of a downgrading of the whole process to a workflow. I imagine it this way: the user's selection/confirmation of the other team and time triggers a delayed (50 hour) expression of a match function and also a lock to the selected time period of both users, so that they cannot schedule another play. I will give a try to that. But I couldn't find a tutorial or code explanation for stonepath. Do you have any link for that or another recommendation like workflow etc.? I have no experience in any of the workflow gems.

Comment: Thank you for that, so I really had to read all of this pdf. It seems as if AASM gem is also enough for me. Just one last question since I have no experience with these: I suppose a model may contain multiple workflows for multiple processes, right? So, stuff like "aasm_event :get_dry_goods do____transitions :to => :dry_goods_phase, :from => :drop_off_orders_phase___end" are all different and separate workflows?

Comment: Not sure of AASM, but my choice of SM https://github.com/geekq/workflow (named workflow but is more a state machine than a workflow) supports multiple workflows.